# Responsive Background Image with center/cover

Tags: responsive-design, background-image

I have this html syntax:

```
<div class="kalis-img" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/myimage.jpg);"></div>
```

I have defined in CSS:

```
.kalis-img {
    background: center center/cover no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

which works fine if I want to have the image at 300px. I tried setting `width:100%;height:auto;` to make this responsive but instead I get a blank image. Is there a way to make a background image, responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea for you:
[the end result](https://s.codepen.io/panchroma/debug/brWdjz/NQMzYnwmBKNk)
[code view](https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/brWdjz)

**HTML**

```
<div class="kalis-img" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.kalis-img {   
 background:url(path_to_image) center center/cover no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 /*     height: auto; */
 /*     display: inline-block; */
 height:66.67vw;
}
```

You'll see that I'm setting the height as 66.67vw, which is equivalent to 2/3rds of the viewport width, choose whatever makes sense for your design.

**Edit**

> Right now it's 4 rectangles next to each other, each 300px, taking a
>   max width of 1200px. When the screen becomes smaller, I would like the
>   width & height of these 4 rectangles to become smaller, so that they
>   are still on the same row.

See if this does the trick for you: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/wqqoZj

The important bits of the code are:
**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image image1" ></div>
   ...
  <div class="image image4" ></div>
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.image {
  height:400px; /* adjust as required */
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
  float:left;    
  box-sizing: border-box;  /* needed to remove browser padding or borders which could break single row layout */
}

.image1,
.image2,
.image3,
.image4{
 background:url(path_to_image) center center/cover no-repeat;

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi David, your solution changes the height dynamically. Instead I would like the width to change dynamically. I tried to swap around your solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: I have 4 of these elements in the same row, by the way. Hence I would like the width to be smaller, so that they don't fall apart when the screen becomes smaller.

Comment: Hi @JoannaMikalai, I'm not clear on what you want, is it 4 columns, which cover the full width of the screen, each of them the full height of the screen?

Comment: Right now it's 4 rectangles next to each other, each 300px, taking a max width of 1200px. When the screen becomes smaller, I would like the width & height of these 4 rectangles to become smaller, so that they are still on the same row.